# Apk installation fails in phonegap

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova, phonegap-build

I am working on phonegap project. I have one apk file which is working fine and installing properly on android device, but I want to do some modification in that apk file, for that what i am doing is, just renaming it's extention from apk to zip and simply extracting it, and doing some changes in HTML file which is located at asset/www folder. And after modifying all necessary changes again compressing that folder back to zip and again back to apk. I just want to install that modified apk file onto android device. But while installing it is parsing properly but getting error Apk not installed, I think I am getting this error because that modified apk is not signed and zipalign.

So my main question is, how can i signed my apk using jarsigner and zipalign mechanism is there any java code or command so that i can achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to edit the html of the page after installing the APK? If you edit the HTML within eclipse then create the APK, does it work correctly?

Comment: Actually I am trying to create apk manually, for this I have created one folder in my maven based java project, whatever minimum number of files are required to create a apk file, I have already pasted it into that folder like .dex, res etc... and just trying update HTML from asset/www/folder. After this just bundling whole folder into an apk file through java code. But I think i am getting error, because the apk which I am creating manually is not signed, looking for a exact solution.

Comment: For more clarity i have edited my question